# Unit test failing due to a lack of rounding--how do I satisfy both unit tests?

Tags: python, function, unit-testing, rounding

**Issue:** When I use the round() function on total_gains variable (in order to satisfy the unit test for Task 1), it also rounds the output for Task 2, causing me to fail the unit test for task 2

**Task 1:** Create a function that enables investors to increase gains depending on the amount invested. The more you invest, the greater your rate of return.

**Task 1 Code:**

```
multiplier_amount = 1000000


def calculate_gains(amount_inv=0.0):
    # base amount gain margin
    gain_margin = 0.10

    total_gains = 0
    total_amount = 0

    if amount_inv > 1000:

        # check whether the invested amount is greater than the multiplier amount
        if amount_inv > multiplier_amount:
            # +1% each time the amount surpasses increments of 1000000
            multiplier_mod = (amount_inv // multiplier_amount)
            # update the `gain_margin` by the multiplier mod
            gain_margin = (gain_margin + multiplier_mod) / 100

        # calculate the total amount of gains
        total_gains = (amount_inv * gain_margin)

        # calculate the total amount plus the gain margin
        total_amount = amount_inv + total_gains

    # return the gains, the full amount and the gain margin
    return total_gains, total_amount, round(gain_margin, 3)
```

**Task 1 Unit Test failed when calling calculate_gains(3000000)**

**Console Output:**

163999.99999999997

**Expected Output:**

164000.0

**Task 2:**
**- Reuse the base function from Task 1 to calculate the return on investment.**

- Loop over a period of 12 months to calculate the total for each period.
- Return the accumulated estimated value for a period of 12 months

**Task 2 Code:**

```
from ReturnOnInvestment1 import calculate_gains


def calculate_gains_over_time(amount_inv=0.0, period=12):
    """
        Calculating the return gains of a given amount invested based on a period of application.
        :param amount_inv: the money amount invested
        :param period: application period
        :return:
        """

    # call the base `calculate_gains` function to estimate the gains for the first period
    total_amount = calculate_gains(amount_inv)
    # calculate the first period before entering the loop
    new_amount = amount_inv
    # loop through the specified period to calculate the gain of each month
    # 1 to period-1 because the first period gains is already calculated above
    for i in range(1, period + 1):
        # call the function to update the value based on the period inside the loop and the updated amount
        total_gains, total_amount, gain_margin = calculate_gains(new_amount)
        new_amount = total_amount  # update the `new_amount` variable

    # return the final amount
    return new_amount


print(calculate_gains_over_time(amount_inv=3000000, period=12))
```

**Task 2 Unit Test passed:**
**Console Output:**

4411734.480111958

I tried rounding total_gains in Task 1, which resulted in a passing unit test for Task 1. Unfortunately that also rounded my answer for Task 2, which only accepts a decimal answer as output.

Comment: How are you actually running these tests?  When I call `calculate_gains(3000000)` without the `round()` I get `(93000.0, 3093000.0, 0.031)` as output.  Whatever is giving you the rounding error is happening outside of that function.

Comment: Right, the unit test for Task 1 is calling the function using 4000000. The unit tests are from a built-in program so I have no control over them. Task 2 does a separate test and calls the function using 3000000. I am required to pass Task 1 calling calculate_gains(4000000) and Task 2 with calculate_gains_over_time(amount_inv=3000000, period=12)

Comment: Are you not allowed to know what the test is actually checking for, or what the output of your function is supposed to be?  That seems... difficult.